# how can i modify link in google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications, hyperlink

i want to implement my web app using app script like this way.

the case : USER get the link from email with some id inside the link, lets say USER link is ->

```
https://myweb.co.id/appScript/?yourID=12345
```

when USER click the link, USER directly to open myweb.co.id with USER DATA ID "12345"

i dont know how to implement in my code to get the same link like i want.

```
    function doGet(e) { var data = "12345";
  if (e.parameter.id == data) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('success')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
  } else {
      return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate().setTitle('MY. WEB').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  }
}
```

Comment: What's "myweb.co.id"?

Answer (score 1):

### You can not change the URL of the WebApp, but you can embed the WebApp in your existing website

You can do this with

```
<frame src="WebAppUrl" >
```

It is important to specify within the WebApp

`.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)`